# How does LINQ's "Where" method works?

Tags: c#, linq

Exactly how LINQ's "where" method is defined? I'm guessing implementation is something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where ( this partialParent, Func<bla,bla> myDelegate )
```

Now if I invoke Where method like this:

```
from c in context.Con
where ( c.Col1 == c.Col2 )
select c
```

I'm guessing `"c.Col1 == c.Col2"` is passed down and some `foreach` loop does the checking. But what is going on when I invoke where like this:

```
where ( c.Col1 == c.Col2 || c.Col3 == c.Col4 )
```

Does the two "checks" are passed down as a whole expression? Maybe I'm missing something very simple.

Comment: I recommend reading http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-2-quot-where-quot.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query syntax you mention for `where` basically creates a method and delegate, and calls the method syntax version with it. Whatever you call `where` with is turned into a single method and then called via a delegate on each element of the source sequence.

So possibly what you mean by the two checks being passed as a whole expression; that's what is happening...

```
where ( c.Col1 == c.Col2 || c.Col3 == c.Col4 )
```

it turned into a single method call like this:

```
bool MethodExample(var c){
  return ( c.Col1 == c.Col2 || c.Col3 == c.Col4 );
}
```

and is then called on each element. (obviously the above is pseudo-code)

Answer (score 5):

In the case of linq-to-objects, you can consider it to be the equivalent of `enumeration.Where(c => c.Col1 == c.Col2)` or `enuemration.Where(c => c.Col1 == c.Col2 || c.Col3 == c.Col4)`.

The easiest way to implement `Where` would be something like:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(this IEnumerable<T> src, Func<T, bool> pred)
{
  foreach(T item in src)
    if(pred(item))
      yield return item;
}
```

Though if you look at the code in reflector you'll see a lot of optimisations on this basic idea.

However, it this call to `Where` is just one way that `where` could implemented. Because LINQ queries can be executed against lots of different queryable sources, there are other possibilities. It could for example be turned into a SQL `WHERE` clause on a query sent to the database. It can be informative to execute some queries using Linq2SQL, and run a SQL Profiler and look at what is sent to the server.

Answer (score 2):

The following "pseudo"-code blocks give the same code:

```
// first
from item in sequence
where expression
select item;

// second
sequence.Where(item => expression);
```

It does not matter how many comparisons that are made in *expression* as long as it yields a boolean result. It's still one expression.

This means that the following two are also identical:

```
// first
from c in context.Con
where ( c.Col1 == c.Col2 || c.Col3 == c.Col4 )
select c;

// second
context.Con.Where(c => c.Col1 == c.Col2 || c.Col3 == c.Col4);
```