# Update records using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to set a value in a table for a subset of rows. In SQL, I would do this:

```
UPDATE dbo.Person SET is_default = 0 WHERE person_id = 5
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?

I currently use the:

```
var result = (from p in Context.People....)
```

notation.

Is there an update method I can use? Or do I have to get all the records, then update them one-by-one in a Foreach?

Is this the most efficient way, if this is even possible?

```
(from p in Context.person_account_portfolio where p.person_id == personId select p)
   .ToList()
   .ForEach(
       x =>
       x.is_default =
       false);
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

This worked best.

```
(from p in Context.person_account_portfolio 
 where p.person_id == personId select p).ToList()
                                        .ForEach(x => x.is_default = false);

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: will you please explain this query ? @Craig

Comment: Yes! It is necessary!

Comment: Is there a reason for the List and ForEach this is not necessary? it's extra Computation and Memory allocation that is un-necessary? I have posted a more efficient example on the Question...

Answer (score 73):

I assume `person_id` is the primary key of `Person` table, so here's how you update a single record:

```
Person result = (from p in Context.Persons
              where p.person_id == 5
              select p).SingleOrDefault();

result.is_default = false;

Context.SaveChanges();
```

and here's how you update multiple records:

```
List<Person> results = (from p in Context.Persons
                        where .... // add where condition here
                        select p).ToList();

foreach (Person p in results)
{
    p.is_default = false;
}

Context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 17):

Just as an addition to the accepted answer, you might find your code looking more consistent when using the LINQ method syntax:

```
Context.person_account_portfolio
.Where(p => person_id == personId)
.ToList()
.ForEach(x => x.is_default = false);
```

`.ToList()` is neccessary because .ForEach() is defined only on `List<T>`, not on `IEnumerable<T>`. Just be aware `.ToList()` is going to execute the query and load ALL matching rows from database before executing the loop.

Comment: Neatest solution. It's worth noting that ToList will create a copy of the IEnumerable, and run a copy constructor on all the elements. I'm not judging, I use it all the time and really like List->ForEach. I'm just saying if you have millions of person_account_portfolio's and batter this all day long then it may be prudent to use the less pretty IEnumerable->foreach instead.

Comment: In my case, I've simply wrote the same without ToList() and it works just fine, as far as I know. I don't feel the same code without ToList, that should run the ForEach to the IEnumerable, is so less pretty as @Vman says.

Answer (score 7):

You have two options as far as I know:

1. Perform your query, iterate over it to modify the entities, then call `SaveChanges()`.
2. Execute a SQL command like you mentioned at the top of your question. To see how to do this, take a look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592907.aspx).

If you use option 2, you're losing some of the abstraction that the Entity Framework gives you, but if you need to perform a very large update, this might be the best choice for performance reasons.

Answer (score 3):

***Yes. You can use foreach to update the records in linq.There is no performance degrade.***

you can verify that the standard [Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) operator is implemented using the [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3862810/3186681) construct introduced in C# 2.0.

> The [use of yield has an interesting benefit](http://www.hugoware.net/blog/the-mystery-behind-yield) which is that the query is
>   not actually evaluated until it is iterated over, either with a
>   foreach statement or by manually using the underlying GetEnumerator
>   and MoveNext methods

For instance,

```
var query = db.Customers.Where (c => c.Name.StartsWith ("A"));
query = query.Where (c => c.Purchases.Count() >= 2);
var result = query.Select (c => c.Name);

foreach (string name in result)   // Only now is the query executed!
   Console.WriteLine (name);
```

**Exceptional operators are:** First, ElementAt, Sum, Average, All, Any, ToArray and ToList force immediate query evaluation.

So no need to scare to use `foreach` for `update` the linq result.

In your case code sample given below will be useful to update many properties,

```
 var persons = (from p in Context.person_account_portfolio where p.person_name == personName select p);

//TO update using foreach

foreach(var person in persons)
{
//update property values
}
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: `yield` is a red herring: that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to get all records, update them and then call `SaveChanges`.

Answer (score 1):

Strangely, for me it's SubmitChanges as opposed to SaveChanges:

```
    foreach (var item in w)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) == item.ID)
        {
            item.Sort = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            item.Sort = null;
        }
        db.SubmitChanges();            
    }
```

Comment: Read here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10980619/what-is-technical-difference-between-submitchanges-in-linq-to-sql-and-savechange
And you probably shouldn't call `.SubmitChanges()`on each iteration...

Comment: If code is run as Language = C# Statement(s). It shouldn't cause problems you will need to commonly re-execute it after every every execution.

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult OrderDel(int id)
    {
        string a = Session["UserSession"].ToString();
        var s = (from test in ob.Order_Details where test.Email_ID_Fk == a && test.Order_ID == id select test).FirstOrDefault();
        s.Status = "Order Cancel By User";
        ob.SaveChanges();
        //foreach(var updter in s)
        //{
        //    updter.Status = "Order Cancel By User";
        //}


        return Json("Sucess", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } <script>
            function Cancel(id) {
                if (confirm("Are your sure ? Want to Cancel?")) {
                    $.ajax({

                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("OrderDel", "Home")/' + id,
                        datatype: 'JSON',
                        success: function (Result) {
                            if (Result == "Sucess")
                            {
                                alert("Your Order has been Canceled..");
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (Msgerror) {
                            alert(Msgerror.responseText);
                        }


                    })
                }
            }

        </script>
```