# Linq update multiple columns

Tags: c#, linq

This is the first time I saw this kind of coding style `(I admit it)`

```
(from p in Context.person_account_portfolio 
 where p.person_id == personId select p).ToList()
       .ForEach(x => x.is_default = false);
```

> As I understand the code correctly it will update only 1 column right?.
>
> **Question: How to update many column using craig code?. Let say 2 or more columns**

My way of updating a column in `c#` is something like this

```
var qry = (from a in db.Table
           where a.Id == paramId
           select a).ToList();

        foreach (var item in qry) {
            item.Name = "John";
            item.LastName = "Dela Cruz";
            . . . . 
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Code from **[Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832684/update-records-using-linq/20930993#20930993)**

Comment: Look at ekads answer to the same question about updating 1 record and use that instead. Unless you are storing multiple entries with the same id then use ekads answer instead as it is much clearer

Comment: @CodingYoshi hes way is like in my current way of coding?.

Comment: No he says that you do not need a loop and he is right. How many records are you expecting?

Comment: @CodingYoshi just for example 5 records.

Comment: Use qxg answer below if you have multiple records.

Comment: @CodingYoshi yes I try it but I have a problem. I leave a comment on his answer please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a LINQ question. Instead it's a delegate/lambda question.

Just use this code inside the `ForEach`

```
(x) =>
{
    x.Name = "John";
    x.LastName = "Dela Cruz";
    . . . . 
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Note the open/close curly braces.

Comment: I have an error in ForEach side. The `x` it says `The name `x` does not exist in the current context`. Even I change it in any letters i got same error.

Comment: Please check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx#Statement%20Lambdas

Comment: @qxg I think the SaveChanges should be outside the loop so it does the whole update in one trip.

Comment: @CodingYoshi and qxg. Thanks man.. Life Saver :) + 1. Just a little question. It will loop all in one way trip(eg 5 records)?

Comment: @Kira, Not sure it answers your question: yes, it will create one call to database if you put db.SaveChanges() outside of the loop.

Comment: @qxg got it.. Can I re-use it?. Or it is possible to declare it in a `variable`?.