# how to update datarow in datatable using LINQ C#?

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, datarow

i want to update `datatable`(dtTaskandBugs) on some condition.
want to update storyid of all the row in the datatable when the id(which is a column of the Datatable) is passed as paramter to the `function` GetStoryid.
this is my code below it's not working (nothing happening)

```
  dtTaskandBugs.Select(string.Format("Storyid = '{0}'", dtTaskandBugs.Rows)).ToList<DataRow>().ForEach(
                r =>
                {
                    r["Storyid"] = GetStoryid(r["Id"]);
                });
```

Comment: You can refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832684/update-records-using-linq

Comment: i need for datatow

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
string.Format("Storyid = '{0}'", dtTaskandBugs.Rows)
```

You are passing the number of rows in this table as argument to `DataTable.Select` which filters the rows, so probably doesn't return any rows.

I suggest a simple `foreach`-loop since you want to update all rows:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dtTaskandBugs.Rows)
      row ["Storyid"] = GetStoryid(row["Id"]);
```

Comment: Want to use Linq rather than foreach alone(as it is taking too much time).

Comment: need LINQ solution

Comment: @MohitMonga: a plain foreach loop is faster because it doesn't need to create an intermediate list just to be able to use `List.ForEach`(which isn't LINQ at all). Note that LINQ also uses loop, you just don't see them

Comment: @MohitMonga: Use LINQ to find rows(to update or whatever), don't use it to modify anything. LINQ should not cause any side-effects, it's just a query tool.

Comment: pls provide Linq solution will try pls

Comment: @MohitMonga: There's absolutely no use-case for LINQ here. Do you want to filter the rows which you're gonna update? Then it's not clear

Comment: @MohitMonga: well, what's wrong with `GetStoryid(row["Id"])` then?

Comment: taking too much time for 7k records

Comment: @MohitMonga: then you want help to improve the performance of `GetStoryid` without even showing it.