# How to update two columns with same name from two tables in a join query

Tags: sql, linq

I am getting an error:

> Property or Indexer cannot be assigned to "--" it is read only

when trying to update two columns with the same name in two tables in a join query. How do I get this to work? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to update p.Processed and t.Processed column to true for every row in the tables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832684/update-records-using-linq

Comment: This does not solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anonymous object created in your projection ("select new" part) is read-only and its properties are not tracked by data context by any means.

Instead, you can try this:

```
//...
select new 
{
    p1 = p,
    p2 = t
}

foreach (var row in updates)
{
    row.p1.Processed = true;
    row.p2.Processed = true;
}
```

In order to improve performance you may also want to take a look at batch update capabilities of Entity Framework Extensions (if you are using Entity Framework): https://entityframework-extensions.net/overview

Comment: Thank you, this answered my question and solved my issue. Also, I am using EF so thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's due to anonymous type properties are read only, from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types):

> Anonymous types provide a convenient way to encapsulate a set of
>   read-only properties into a single object without having to explicitly
>   define a type first.

I suggest you to create a custom class with the two entities you need (a DTO):

```
public class PassengerDTO
{
  public Passenger Passenger {get;set}
  public PassengerItinerary PassengerItinerary {get;set}
}
```

And use it in your projection, You need the entity instances and not just the properties you want to modify because, when you modify the `Processed` property in the `foreach` the proxy class that represent your entity is going to change the status of you entity to `Updated`.