# ASP.NET Core MVC - how to add button to Home view that executes SQL?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am working on an ASP.NET Core MVC app using EF Core on .NET 5.0. Database is SQL Server.

I have a single user who will be testing my app at this point. For testing purposes, I want to have two buttons on my Home view called "Make User Admin" and "Make User Normal". I want to hard-code SQL in my app so that when the user clicks "Make User Admin", the following SQL query will be run:

```
UPDATE LoginTable SET IsAdmin = true WHERE Username = "username_here";
```

And when the user clicks "Make User Normal", this will be executed:

```
UPDATE LoginTable SET IsAdmin = false WHERE Username = "username_here";
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this using ASP.NET Core MVC. I imagine that the methods to call the SQL queries will be placed in the Home Controller, but I don't know how to generate a SQL query in my code and then execute it against the database at the click of a button.

[ This may be bad practice, but it's just a simple solution to test some things out that will not be included in the production release =) ]

How can I do this?

Comment: You can redirect the button click to a controller action that executes the SQL, instead of having it hardcoded in your HTML.

Comment: Vinicius - I was figured that was likely the case, but I don't know how to write that code in the controller. I've found documentation for a method called FromSQLRaw, but I don't know how to access that method.

Comment: I realize now that my question was worded as such that it sounded like I wanted to hard-code the SQL specifically in the view. I have modified the question to indicate that I'm just looking to hard-code SQL in my app in general. Good find!

Comment: In this case, I recommend that you use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) to build your queries, it's very intuitive.

Comment: [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832684/update-records-using-linq), might help you with LINQ.

Comment: Hmm... that documentation was easy to follow and I got it up and running quickly. Thank you! If you want to leave an actual answer recommending LINQ with that documentation then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks! Already did! Glad you could make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect the button click to a controller action that executes the SQL, instead of having it hardcoded in your HTML.

To create a query in C#, you can use [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).
You can see more LINQ examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832684/update-records-using-linq).

Simple example:

```
    //Specify the data source.
    int[] scores = new int[] { 97, 92, 81, 60 };

    //Define the query expression.
    IEnumerable<int> scoreQuery =
        from score in scores
        where score > 80
        select score;
```